# WDS Error: A connection to the deployment share could not be made

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-xp, deployment, wds, mdt-2010

We currently have a WDS server that we use for imaging both Windows XP and Windows 7 machines. We use MDT 2010 to add drivers to the WIM files. It works for all of our existing hardware, but we recently got in some Dell E6420 machines that we can't get to image (we're trying to install XP). After the machine downloads the WIM it throws an error:

> A connection to the deployment share (\\servername\DeploymentShare) could not be made. DHCP Lease was not obtained for any Networking device! Possible Cause: Check physical connection. Abort - Abort Litetouch and cleanup (No Recovery). Retry - Retry network operation. Ignore - Cancel out of Litetouch (Retry later).

I don't think this is a network or DHCP issue, since all other models work. I think it's a driver issue, but I added the network driver from Dell's site to the WIM using MDT so I'm not sure why it isn't working. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need to add the drivers for the NIC into the Boot.WIM. I know you said you use MDT to add drivers to your WIMs but are you sure you're adding the correct ones?

[Dell provides a WinPE Driver pack](http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/enterprise-client/w/wiki/2065.dell-driver-cab-files-for-enterprise-client-os-deployment.aspx). I created a folder under the Out-of-Box drivers called WinPE and a selection profile called WinPE that only selects that folder. For the Boot.WIM setup in MDT I have it set to only use the [WinPE profile for the Boot.WIMs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l17Ib.png).

Answer (score 1):

WDS is interesting in that it grabs one DHCP address at PXE boot, and then grabs another one right after that after WinPE has started.  What happens on some networks is that the DHCP server can't respond quickly enough to support this behavior.

I have been able to remedy this exact problem on some networks by enabling portfast on the switches/switch ports involved.

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to connect to the share and no DHCP lease, then your problem starts with the Network. Don't take for granted that everything works. Check out more than 2 of the laptops as I have seen those specifically having board problems with the network. Load the OS manually and verify a few of the devices.

If you have updated the WIM already, copy the windows image to usb and load it that way, once you get the image loaded on the device, you can see that either the driver worked or it didn't. I would guess that it didn't.

Finally, make sure you are not mixing 32/64 drivers.

Dan

Comment: This model has the same issue in multiple offices using different WDS servers and many different laptops of the same model. I will try the straight WIM file and post my results. Thanks for the suggestion.